# bbc-microbit does not go into pairing mode

Tags: python, bluetooth, bbc-microbit

Just received a BBC-microbit via eBay and am trying to got it to work so I can help a grandchild learn coding via Scratch.

I dragged scratch-microbit-1.1.0.hex to the BBC.
After reset "vavov" keeps scrolling on the BBC screen.

Then tried putting it into pairing mode by (1) pressing buttons A & B (2) pressing the Reset button (3) releasing Reset (4) releasing A B

I expected to see PAIRING MODE or the Bluetooth icon on the BBC LED matrix, but only vavov shows.

I thought that maybe scratch-microbit-1.1.0.hex is causing the problem and reset the BBC to factory settings via OutOfBoxExperience-v2.hex. Still can't put the BBC into pairing mode.

Is there a way to to send programs to the BBC via USB? Is Yes then how?

---

I tried writing a small Scratch program and in the editor adding the microbit extension. Got no devices found.

---

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe try using the MakeCode editor https://makecode.microbit.org/? There are some instructions at: https://support.microbit.org/support/solutions/articles/19000013986-how-do-i-transfer-my-code-onto-the-micro-bit-via-usb

Comment: Found a way to create hex files from MicroPython via:
https://python.microbit.org/v/2.0

It recogniizes the microbit via the USB link, but shows error when I try to sent the hex file to the microbit. Was able to download the hex file and then drag and drop it to the microbit via File explorer. 

***

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HAx9sJB1_eY&feature=youtu.be shows how to interact (even set IO lines) with microbit a command at a time via REPL or UREPL,which I didn't find on Internet. It acts as Telnet or similar. Does anyone know how to find that program?

Comment: Sent following as hex to the microbit and tor error message on the micro about the sleep commands. Does someone know why?

rom microbit import *

while True:
   display.scroll('Hello, World!')
    display.show(Image.HEART)
    microbit.sleep(1000)
    display.scroll('Bye')
    microbit.sleep(1000)
    microbit.temperature()

Comment: You seem like you are after help getting started with the micro:bit. It is difficult to help when you are mixing up lots of questions. I would suggest you separate the different questions in to different posts. There is a good guide on getting started at: https://microbit.org/get-started/first-steps/set-up/ and good support at: https://support.microbit.org/support/home. If you want to do micropython, then I would recommend: https://codewith.mu/en/tutorials/1.0/microbit

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to to send programs to the BBC via USB? Is Yes then how?

Yes. I recommend using [Microbit MakeCode](https://makecode.microbit.org/) to create your program. It is very similar to Scratch. Attach your Microbit via a USB cable. (Make sure this is a data transfer cable, and not just a charging cable.) When you click on Download (from MakeCode), you will be prompted to do a USB pairing. Follow the instructions to pair your Microbit to your computer. Once paired, clicking 'Download' will transfer the .hex file directly to your Microbit. No need to manually copy the file across.